# Compiler rejects type signature of data constructor

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell. When I compile the code:

```
data Bintree a = Nulltree | Node (Bintree a) a (Bintree a)
Nulltree :: Bintree a
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid type signature: Nulltree :: Bintree a Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

So how do I prevent this. I tried writing:

```
data Bintree a = Nulltree | Node (Bintree a) a (Bintree a)
Nulltree :: a -> Bintree a
```

but this gives the same error.

Comment: I wrote an entire answer to this, but you deleted the question before I could post it, so now it's gone. Please think and think again and think yet again before deleting a question. You can always *edit* your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In standard Haskell, you cannot give type signatures to data constructors. The line

```
data Bintree a = Nulltree | Node (Bintree a) a (Bintree a)
```

implies that `Nulltree :: BinTree a`. You don't need to say it yourself, and you can't. Using the `GADTSyntax` language extension, you could instead write

```
data Bintree a where
  Nulltree :: BinTree a
  Node :: Bintree a -> a -> Bintree a -> Bintree a
```

(Thanks to chi for pointing out that `GADTSyntax` is sufficient, and the not-so-beginner-friendly `GADTs` extension is not required.)

Comment: Indeed, enabling `GATDs` would be inappropriate for a beginner. There is however the lesser extension `GADTSyntax` which enables only the new syntax without extending the expressive power of data type declarations (i.e., each constructor must return exactly a `Bintree a`).

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to provide a type signature for `Nulltree`. It's already clear to the compiler what it is.

If you want to create a particular empty tree, you could go:

```
emptyTree :: Bintree Int -- for example
emptyTree = Nulltree
```